# While using DPDK application, rte_eth_dev_count is returning 0 always

Tags: dpdk

I have configured NIC cards as below:-

```
[root@localhost ethtool]# ../../tools/dpdk-devbind.py -s


Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:81:00.0 'NetXtreme BCM5722 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express' drv=igb_uio unused=tg3

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:02:00.0 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection' if=ens513f0 drv=ixgbe unused=igb_uio
0000:02:00.1 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection' if=ens513f1 drv=ixgbe unused=igb_uio
0000:04:00.0 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection' if=enp4s0f0 drv=igb unused=igb_uio
0000:04:00.3 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection' if=enp4s0f3 drv=igb unused=igb_uio

Other network devices
=====================
<none>

Crypto devices using DPDK-compatible driver
===========================================
<none>

Crypto devices using kernel driver
==================================
0000:84:00.0 'DH895XCC Series QAT' drv=dh895xcc unused=qat_dh895xcc,igb_uio

Other crypto devices
====================
<none>
```

When i run ethtool sample application it is giving error as 0 NIC ports as shown below:-

```
[root@localhost ethtool]# ./ethtool-app/ethtool-app/x86_64-native-    EAL: Detected 47 lcore(s)
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.3 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
Number of NICs: 0
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
Cause: No available NIC ports!
```

Can someone help me in configuring ports if port configuration is wrong or something else.

Comment: I am having the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636516/how-to-fix-no-valid-ports-issue-in-dpdk-18-02-while-building-the-application

Answer (score 0):

The above error was coming because the below driver are not supported:-
0000:81:00.0 'NetXtreme BCM5722 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express' drv=igb_uio unused=tg3

So Binding DPDK with supported driver solved the problem.

Comment: Which driver did you use?

Comment: @Ganga `igb_uio` should have worked, since I see no other compatible driver in the dpdk-devbind output. Which driver worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

The dpdk-devbind.py tool might be a bit misleading here. Not all of the devices using DPDK-compatible driver is in fact supported by DPDK.

Here is the list of supported Broadcom NICs in DPDK:

http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/nics/bnxt.html

Looks like the BCM5722 is not there.

On the other hand, it looks like you have four other NICs, which are supported by the DPDK:

```
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.3 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
```

So you need to bind one of those to igb_uio and try to run the example again.