# How to fix "no valid ports" issue in dpdk-18.02 while building the application?

Tags: c, linux, ethernet, nic, dpdk

Building an application using dpdk-v18.02 and getting an error as "no valid ports".

I tried dpdk-v19.02 and it's giving the same error.

This is the error:

```
EAL: Detected 40 lcore(s)
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/.rte_unix
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: PCI device 0000:04:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 10ee:9038 xnic
EAL: Requested device 0000:04:00.0 cannot be used
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Error: no valid ports
```

The port is already bound to the driver:

```
dpdk/usertools/# python dpdk-devbind.py --bind=igb_uio 04:00.0
0000:04:00.0 already bound to driver igb_uio, skipping
```

Checking port bound as python dpdk-devbind.py --status

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:04:00.0 'Device 9038' drv=igb_uio unused=
```

Comment: `EAL: Requested device 0000:04:00.0 cannot be used`  Does DPDK have a driver for this NIC?

Comment: Yes, I believe. `drv=igb_uio` is the driver that I used before with different NIC.

Comment: igb_uio is the generic kernel driver to pass control to DPDK.  DPDK needs to have a userspace driver which supports the card.

Comment: Yes, I do have that. I added that driver within dpdk and did run make successfully at dpdk.

Comment: Crank up the log level and look at the messages.

Answer (score 0):

here are the list of [nics supported](http://core.dpdk.org/supported/nics/intel/) with PMD under DPDK. Looks like `Device 9038` is not in the list.

For non supported DPDK NIC, please use PCAP PMD to interface to DPDK application. Steps to get started

1. build appropriate DPDK version with PCAP PMD enabled
2. add extra args to DPDK application as `--no-pci --vdev=net_pcap0,iface=[name of nic interface]`